Understanding how the Acknowedge number is subsequently used by a TCP client
I understand the Acknowledgement number (from e.g a server perspective) represents the sequence number plus the received number of bytes, plus one (suggesting the next byte number it expects from the client).
When the client receives this acknowlegement number, does the TCP implementation actually set the following client sequence number to this acknowledgement number (i.e, does the ack number from the server become the next seq number of the client, and directly get used as the offset for the beginning of the next segment payload?)
Or, instead, does it read the ack number, compare it to the seq number + sent payload size, and act depending on equality/inequality?

First, understand that TCP does not have clients or servers. TCP creates a TCP connection between equal TCP peers. Client/server is an application concept. Either TCP end acts the same and uses information the same way.

Yes, I do appreciate  that, I was just using them for naming each side in my example! Cheers.

An acknowledgement by either end is acknowledging receipt of all bytes prior to the acknowledgement number.
The acknowledgment number is the number of the next expected data byte from the other side. The number sequence is different for each side. A to B would use a sequence starting with the sequence number A set up in the handshake, and B to A would start with the sequence number B set up in the handshake.
You cannot compare the sequence numbers in both directions to each other.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
